# How to translate the post in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to make a multilingual website using `i18n`.

I have translated almost all the text, but I can’t even imagine how to translate my posts. I am using mixins in my project.

[img (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CVJc.png)

**HTML post detail template:**

```
<h3>
    {% trans post.title %}
</h3>
<h6 style="float: right; opacity: 0.5; margin-top: 6px; margin-right: 30px;"> 
    {{ post.date_pub }}
</h6>
<div style="clear: right;"></div>
<p>
    {{ post.body|safe }}
</p>
```

**models.py:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
                title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
                slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
                body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, db_index=True)
                description = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, db_index=True)
                tags = models.ManyToManyField('tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
                date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

                def get_absolute_url(self):
                    return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

                def get_update_url(self):
                    return reverse('post_update_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

                def get_delete_url(self):
                    return reverse('post_delete_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

                def save (self, *args, **kwargs):
                    if not self.id:
                        self.slug = gen_slug(self.title)
                    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

                def __str__(self):
                    return self.title

                class Meta:
                    ordering = ['-date_pub']
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'tags', 'description']

        widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'body': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'tags': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def clean_slug(self):
        new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()

        if new_slug == 'create':
            raise ValidationError('Slug may not be "Create"')
        return new_slug
```

**views.py**

```
class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
    model = Post
    template = 'main/post_detail.html'

class PostCreate(LoginRequiredMixin ,ObjectCreateMixin, View):
    form_model = PostForm
    template = 'main/post_create_form.html'
    raise_exception = True

class PostUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, ObjectUpdateMixin, View):
    model = Post
    form_model = PostForm
    template = 'main/post_update_form.html'
    raise_exception = True

class PostDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, ObjectDeleteMixin, View):
    model = Post
    template = 'main/post_delete_form.html'
    redirect_url = 'posts_list_url'
    raise_exception = True
```

**utils.py**

```
class ObjectDetailMixin:
    model = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request, slug):
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
        return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj, 'admin_object': obj, 'detail': True})

class ObjectCreateMixin:
    form_model = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_model()
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = self.form_model(request.POST)

        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_obj = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_obj)
        return render(request, self.template, 'main/tag_create.html', context={'form': bound_form })

class ObjectUpdateMixin:
    model = None
    form_model = None

    def get(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        bound_form = self.form_model(instance=obj)
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': bound_form, self.model.__name__.lower() :obj})

    def post(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        bound_form = self.form_model(request.POST, instance=obj)

        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_obj = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_obj)
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': bound_form, self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})

class ObjectDeleteMixin:
    model = None
    template = None
    redirect_url = None
    def get(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})

    def post(self, request, slug):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        obj.delete()
        return redirect(reverse(self.redirect_url))
```

Comment: So, you want to translate the user data like the title and the body of your content?

Comment: yes. you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package called django-modeltranslation provides for language-specific mirrored fields in the database that allow for content specific translation. It has very good documentation too - https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.
This is what was used for this website [Language switch example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpJ8Q.jpg)